# Most efficient way to remove values whilst iterating over a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a dataset that contains X,Y Coordinates from several different subjects. So Subject 1 through to n with each having a separate XY. I append all the X and Y coordinates into separate lists of lists called `plot`. So one list is for the X's and one is for the Y's from each subject.

Example Input (3 subjects):

```
Subject 1_X Subject 1_Y Subject 2_X Subject 2_Y Subject 3_X Subject 3_Y
11          45          34          67          8           26
12          46          33          65          7           25
```

Example Output:

```
plot[0] = [[11,34,8],[12,33,7]] #X's
plot[1] = [[45,67,26],[46,65,25]] #Y's
```

Before this, I want to remove both the X and corresponding Y when the X value is below a certain threshold (10 in this case). Example output below: (Subject 3 is removed)

```
plot[0] = [[11,34],[12,33]] #X's
plot[1] = [[45,67],[46,65]] #Y's
```

This process is replicated here:

```
data = [random.sample(range(80), 40) for _ in range(75000)] #Similar size and format

plot = [[],[]]

n = 0
for row in data :
    if n == 0 :
        n+=1
        continue
    x_data = []
    y_data = []
    for (x,y) in [(0,1),(2,3), (4,5), (6,7), (8,9), (10,11), (12,13), (14,15), (16,17), (18,19), (20,21), (22,23), (24,25), (26,27), (28,29), (30,31), (32,33), (34,35), (36,37), (38,39)] : 
        xcoord = float(row[x])
        ycoord = float(row[y])
        if xcoord >= 10 :
            x_data.append(xcoord)
            y_data.append(ycoord)
            plot[0].append(x_data)
            plot[1].append(y_data)
```

This does the job but I use these lists to create an animated scatter plot. Which is extremely slow.

If I remove the function that eliminates the values `< 10` and refine the duplicates, it performs much faster.

```
n=0
for row in data :
    if n == 0 :
        n+=1
        continue 
plot[0].append(list(map(float, row[1:41][::2])))
plot[1].append(list(map(float, row[0:40][::2])))
```

Is there a quicker, more efficient method to iterate and remove specific values more quickly?

I have tried to individually remove values from each source and then append at the end but this is more inefficient than I currently have.

The scatter is called using the following:

`scatter = ax.scatter(plot[0][0], plot[1][0], c=['blue'])`

The animation is called with the following:

```
def animate(i) :
    scatter.set_offsets.([[plot[0][0+i][0], plot[1][0+i][0]]])
```

Comment: Is ```xcoord >= 10``` supposed to be ```xcoord >= n```? Because you don't use the ```n``` anywhere else.

Comment: It might be that your `plot[?].append(?_data)` lines have 2 identations levels too many. I don't know whether it's the copy/paste or you code, but in that latter case, it can already slow it down and make too many copies at the end.
It's not clear also whether you need to keep the lines or not for the plot. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: The 2 results differ (in your 1st result you have lots of duplicate lines, i think 1st result is completely junk). You should place a sample input, and a sample desired output. Also for this dataset 1st approach takes ~1.7s, 2nd takes ~0.9s, but generating the data takes ~3s+.

Comment: @jsmolka yes it is. I didn't want to be specific incase other users wanted to set another threshold

Comment: @FrancisColas I do need to keep the lists to perform a scatter and then animate that scatter. I can see what you're saying. I could the `x_data[]` and `y_data[]` lists and just use `plot[]`

Comment: @CristiFati thanks. I'll look to refine. Quite new to coding. Most of it is terribly inefficient. Have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where you would be better off using `numpy`,
because if I understand you correctly, your code could be simplified to the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 80, size=(2, 75000))  # Get a 2x75000 array of values in range [0, 79]

valid = data[0] >= 10  # Mask based on X-value
xdata, ydata = data[:, valid]  # Cut the parts you want
```

Comment: Sorry I need to remove both X and Y when the X is below 10. I have edited the question to provide an example.

Comment: @PeterJames123 This *does* remove both coordinates. Honestly, if you work with numerical data, numpy is more or less mandatory knowledge, so you should *really* check it out. Becaise I guess if you don't understand numpy arrays my example might be confusing for you.

Comment: Ok. No worries. Thanks